# How do I determine which Windows services were recently disabled?

Tags: windows-10, services, history, event-log, windows-services

Does Windows 10 keep a log of when/which services were enabled/disabled?

How would a person locate this information?

Thanks!

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/855238/find-out-who-disabled-a-windows-service

Comment: `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='system'; id=7040} | Where-Object {$_.message -like "*to disabled*"}`

Comment: @HelpingHand, really, this suffices as a working answer...  I'd just add run this in PowerShell ;-) One might also suggest using Nirsoft's Full Event Log Viewer, which has search capability.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - I added an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Event Log, available by running `eventvwr`, records interactions with the Service Control Manager.  In this case we are interested in the `System` log, the Source is `Service Control Manager` and the EventID is `7040`.

An example event, exported to XML is as follows:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          17/08/2020 14:11:08
Event ID:      7040
Task Category: None
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      asus
Description:
The start type of the Background Intelligent Transfer Service service was changed from demand start to auto start.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7040</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-08-17T13:11:08.7830390Z" />
    <EventRecordID>47575</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="944" ThreadID="19856" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>asus</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">Background Intelligent Transfer Service</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">demand start</Data>
    <Data Name="param3">auto start</Data>
    <Data Name="param4">BITS</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

To export just the values of interest here, i.e. the `CreationTime` and `Message`, the following PowerShell command could be used:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname='system'; id=7040} | Where-Object {$_.message -like "*disabled*"} | select TimeCreated, Message | Out-GridView
```

If you want to break up the parameters of the message, the following PowerShell could be used:

```
$Report = @()
foreach ($e in (Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="system"; id=7040}))
{
   $obj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Time = $e.TimeCreated
    ServiceDisplayName = ([xml]$e.ToXml()).Event.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='param1']")."#text"
    OldState = ([xml]$e.ToXml()).Event.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='param2']")."#text"
    NewState = ([xml]$e.ToXml()).Event.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='param3']")."#text"
    ServiceName = ([xml]$e.ToXml()).Event.SelectSingleNode("//*[@Name='param4']")."#text"
   }
   $Report += $obj
}
$Report | Out-GridView
```